# Websocket Security

Tags: security, authentication, websocket

I am looking to implement web (angular) and iPhone apps using WebSockets to communicate with our server. In the past using HTTP requests we have used hashes using the request data, url, timestamp etc to authenticate and secure the requests.

As far as I am aware we can't send headers with WebSockets requests therefore I am wondering how I can secure each request.

Does anyone have any ideas or good practices?

Comment: Good question.  I've yet to get to point of using websockets but it's something I want to do sooner than later.  I did find this: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/

Comment: At least start with https (WWS actually then). The link from @Rob is your next step.

Comment: @Rob thanks, that is a start. But I wanted an approach which could prevent man in the middle attacks. I can't really find an approach for this, in the past I hashed the whole request along with the request data therefore if someone did even change the request the server would know. I guess I could serialise the data into a string and pass the hash as part of the URL but not sure if this is safe/good practice

Comment: When you say hash, do you mean like a cookie authentication hash?

Comment: @Rob Nope, a has generated via a public/secret key (oauth token for angular) on top of the request specific data such as the ip address, nonce, request data, timestamp etc

Comment: I guess I'm confused. The link I added provides information to prevent man in the middle attacks with tokens.

Comment: @Rob Unless I am mistaken, I don't think it does. The token is generated on the user profile, username, name, id etc not the actual request. Therefore in theory someone could sniff the request midway and change it whereas the token would remain the same?

Comment: According to the websocket protocol, the browser sends masked data (bit shifting, simple to decode) and the server sends the data back with no masking. But since the data is whatever you decide, you can use any javascript encryption you like and decrypt it on the other side. Also, I'm not sure about about angular implementation, but all websocket connections start as HTTP and you can send headers and get/set cookies  at the time of initiation.

Comment: If you're using an https connection, then you would be fine.  Otherwise tokens are pretty much useless over http.  The way I've implemented tokens is to validate them on the server side and not pass back data if the token is invalid.

Comment: Why not just use an https connection?  All webSocket connections are initiated via http or https and then they "upgrade" to the webSocket protocol.  If you initiate via https, it will stay on SSL when it switches to the webSocket protocol, thus prevening man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Once the TLS connection (wss://) is established, as long as the client authenticates the server's certificate, and the server securely authenticates the client, then that specific connection is secure from MitM.  Headers _are_ available to the WS server to help with authenticating the client...  Of course all rules with https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet apply in full force; never accept a non-TLS connection as authenticated, and the authentication cookie must be TLS only and HTTP only: not available to the client's javascript.

Comment: Also, if you do use session tokens in cookies, see also https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet as an additional must for secure authentication with mixing both WebSocket and HTTP traffic...  (Also, didn't have room to add above: Headers, and thus cookies, are only available to the WS server _during the handshake_, so if the session token changes for any reason (which it should every time the user's auth status changes) the WS connection MUST be disconnected and restarted).

Comment: Using cookies can be a problem if your WebSocket server is on a different origin than your page. See https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster-client/issues/9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having secure communication with server includes authenticating both parties to each other. If you need to channel different users with different authentication credentials through one communication channel (which is a rare idea nowadays), you'll need separate authentication. Otherwise, you just need to come up with key distribution scheme (so that your apps know public keys of your server and your server has a protocol of getting acquanted to public keys of clients, there are plenty of patterns for this).

To do that, there is a choice gradient a bit wider than SSL or your own crypto (try to avoid writing your own crypto at any cost).

For webserver-to-browser part of stack, SSL is your only choice, however it shouldn't be considered as a good safety measure, each year unfolds more and more vulnerabilities, cipher degradation cases and trust problems. It carries 20 years of baggage of bad engineering decisions and urgent fixes, so if you can get something better - it's worth doing so. Still, it's much better than nothing for the regular webs.

In your mobile app you could easily use one of a number of cryptographic libraries providing secure session messaging with server with significantly higher security guarantees, no reliance:

- https://github.com/mochtu/libsodium-ios, **libsodium-ios**, an ios wrapper for NaCl, one of the best modern cryptographic libraries, which has lots of novel implementations to ECC cryptography, is highly praised in academic circles and written by a madman keen to have best performance under all circumstances (in short: I adore it :) ).
- **Themis**, a project I'm a contributor in, we have very ObjC-friendly iOS version of our library, and a handy tutorial on doing secure traffic over websockets in iOS: https://www.cossacklabs.com/building-secure-chat

Answer (score 38):

To secure your messages, use WebSockets over SSL/TLS (wss:// instead of ws://). Don't roll your own crypto.

Concerning authentication. The big difference between HTTP and WebSockets is that HTTP is a stateless protocol and WebSockets is not.

With HTTP you have to send headers (cookies, tokens, whatever) with each request. With WebSockets you establish a connection. In the first interactions you can authenticate the client and for the remainder of the connection you know the client is authenticated.

The people at Heroku have described a pattern where the client authenticates using HTTP, gets a ticket and then sends that ticket as a first message over the WebSocket connection. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security

Comment: Could you clarify? There is really very spotty documentation on this. Are you saying I could just use `wss://` and the protocol automatically switches to TLS? What server configuration is needed? I have done this on some servers and have gotten a bad `400 Bad Request` back.

Comment: Of course you'll need to setup your server to be secure. What server configuration is needed depends on what server you're using. Please ask a separate question. I probably can't help you, though.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the SSL/TLS wss:// connection. Always use encrypted traffic. There are several ways to implement a authentication. See here:
http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2015/09/5-ways-to-secure-websocket-rpi.html

Most to all examples use python or nodejs and are directed for the Raspberry Pi but the general concepts are good ideas to consider.  There are links in the post to a SocketRocket helper library that allows you to insert authentication into the auth header (SocketShuttle).

Answer (score 1):

You should secure your connection with SSL/TLS and use https over http and wss over ws. For having auhentication/authorization, you can add query params to the websocket connections and also add something like username/passwprd.
For instanse :

```
wss://example.com/path?username=password=anotherParam=99ace112-dd56-427e-ba3d-9dd23e9c7551
```

yes, in js you cant add your arbitrary header, but you are allowed to add protocols and Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header to your webocket connections and on the server-side authenticate/authorize users based on websocket protocols

Comment: But, even in WSS, the URL is sent in plaintext, no? Meaning that the password and username could be sniffed...

Comment: yes but you can make it much more complicated by sending lots of query params, very complicated decoded params nad also by passing your own invented templates and validate them in the backend

Comment: And yes in js you can't set header for websocket. but you can set this one :
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol   ;) and check whether the client is sending valid string, and if yes, then you will open the socket.

Comment: But you could also just ask the client to authenticate with the token as soon as they connect, and just closing the socket if the authentication failed.

Comment: its not best practice, because everyone can connect and open lots of HTTP connection and just waste your resources and make your server very busy. 

Sec-WebSocket-Protocol will work as pre-connect authentication method and its not included in query param

Comment: That's a good point. Do you have any implementations that you've seen anywhere, with SockJS or Socket.IO for example?

Comment: The url is NOT sent in plaintext when using wss.